# Keep RDP from locking session in Server 2012

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I am running windows Server 2012 with two users. I have an app that takes a screenshot of a game console that runs under each user. The problem I am having is that I can't detach the Remote Desktop Session without causing the process to fail.

Under Server 2003, I was able to use `tscon.exe 0 /dest:console` but running `tscon.exe 2 /dest:console` or rdp-tcp#2 under server 2012 it does not work.

Is there a way I can do this?

Also, unlike when I was using Server 2003, I am running the programs under their own users that are not admins. If that helps.

EDIT: `tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#0 /dest:console /password:ACCPASS` works, but the desktop does not refresh. So every time the script takes another screenshot (every 30 seconds), it is the same as the last one. What I'm trying to do is to get RDP to function like VNC, where the desktop stays active and logged on after disconnect

Comment: I don't know if the screen renders without a session attached. You may need to use something that makes a psudo connection so windows will render the images (it could even capture the images itself)